# Chrome extension manifest handling Pop-Up

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an extension that will simply show an alert box when they go to a certain page.

My test.js content is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("got it !z");
});
```

manifest.json contains:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,  
    "name": "Testing",
    "description": "Sample extension",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "https://*/*"],
    "version": "1.3.2",
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["https://something.something.net/*"],
        "js" : ["js/jquery.js", "js/test.js"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "icons/19x19.png",
            "38": "icons/38x38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Testing of extention",
        "default_popup": "theHtml.html"
    }
}
```

Every time I go to https://something.something.net/* it seems fine (it alerts "got it !z"). Well to be more specific this site is an email site.

But once I open something like compose in gmail? The specific site opens a new small pop-up window, like new _blank window.

After that my extension there is not working. Well my desire is that once it opens the pop-up because it loads a page it should alert("got it !z").

That's my problem, how to include my Manifest in a pop-up page?

this image show that the extension is enabled
[image]

[image]

and this image is showing the pop-up page where i want to simply alert once its open
[image]

Comment: The popup you are referring to on Gmail is not a _blank window. It is actually a div that gets generated when you click the "Compose" button. To trigger an event for that, you would have to use the id or class of the button in a jquery selector to trigger an .Click event.

Comment: gmail "Compose"  i think it is actually a div, 
what I'm referring, is that  the one im using is like goDaddy  or rackspace "Compose", where it will pop up a new page, i just simply use gmail for reference hehehhe my bad... english is not my native peace ,V,,  :)

Comment: i'd need to see the website in question to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: I believe that content scripts should run in popup windows automatically assuming the URL matching is correct. I would double check the URL of the popup with the allowed URLs in the manifest.